# Solution for balancing laptop on pointy surface

Tags: laptop

I am trying to make my laptop sit nicely on top of a pointy surface, and not really managing it.

As you can see from the image, the piano I have doesn't have a natural place for a laptop to sit.

The laptop will stay there unless you need to press a button, then it just falls down.

I can't find anything online that would help, other than buying a floor stand and having it behind the piano.

If anyone has any suggestions, I will be forever in your debt.

[image: laptop sitting on piano]

Comment: Make a fine wood bracket with a flat top and sides to fit the top edge of the piano.

Comment: Possibly mount a shelf on the wall just above the piano, maybe slant it a bit with a stop so the laptop cannot slide off.

Comment: It isn't likely to help you, but I'm using a tablet. It fits nicely on the dedicated spot for sheet music.

Comment: The answers will be dependent on whether you need the screen, or the laptop keyboard, or both. Be more specific. If just the screen, it's a very simple job to open the laptop fully, and rest it on the shelf where the sheet music would go, surely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.

Weather Vale and Elmy. Thanks for your ideas, but unfortunately my laptop doesn't open wide enough for that to work in this circumstance.

Glorfindel, I don't actually have an iPad, but that would be ideal

I went for something closer to what John and Moab suggested, but without the permanency.

I found a laptop stand that had adjustable legs, and I just have it hanging down the back of the piano, next to the wall.  Works ok, although a little fiddly when opening and closing the piano.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are seated at the piano stool, it looks as though you can't use the keyboard at that angle anyway.

If yours is a laptop that will open flat to 180° do that and stand it on the plinth behind the piano keys. The laptop screen will be in about the same position.

There is a lip along the front of the control panel to stop music slipping forwards, as can be seen in this enhanced image. If it doesn't provide enough security, prevent the laptop from slipping with a thin plastic strap or string, going underneath the piano lid and fed though a crack in the piano lid's hinges.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The lid of the piano could prop the laptiop up vertically, like this:

[image]

Black is the piano, blue is the laptop.
Red is some kind of stopper that keeps the lower edge of the laptop from sliding forwards. That could be glue-on rubber stoppers (for small furniture) or just anything you can secure to the piano that is thick enough to stop the laptop from sliding. (Make sure it's not too thick for the piano lid to close.)

You should attatch the stoppers as close to the keys as possible to decrease the angle of the laptop and increase stability.

Typing like this won't be comfortable, but possible.

Comment: Isn't this just about the same as my answer?

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh that's odd. When I wrote mine I didn't see that your answer even existed (and I'm sure that I checked). Do you want to copy the image to your answer?

Comment: No that's fine. The piano image (when enhanced) does show there is a retaining lip along the central part of the control panel. My answer's method was so as not to have to 'modify' the piano itself.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [notebook support](https://www.amazon.com/Notebook-Support/s?k=Notebook%20Support) or something like that.

See, for example: [image]

Comment: Now where do you propose that the asker should fix that to?

Comment: Anywhere, no? you could change angle, don't u see, and you could choice right form-factor one, that you want, I've just formulated the question much clearly for amazon shopping in future.. cheers